# Why is my pregmatch() function returning the line description, which is outside of the capture brackets?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, explode

I'm using this method:

```
$matches;
preg_match('/^days:\s(.*)$/', $line, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 1)
  return explode('; ', $matches[1]);
return array();
```

On a file with lines like:

`days: Monday; Thursday; Friday`,

And the first result (in the example, `Monday`), always comes with the "`days:`" part added on, like this:

```
array[0](
  myObject=>object
  (
    visitors[0]=>array //notice "visitors" is the problem.  It should be "days".
    (
      [0]=>days: Monday
      [1]=>Thursday
      [2]=>Friday
    )
  )
)
```

I thought regex was supposed to return what's inside the brackets (`()`)?

Comment: This doesn't look like the original code. 1) You're exploding on `;` when the delimiter in your example is `,`. 2) Your sample output includes an object, which would never be a result of `preg_match()`. Please post the original, unedited code. (Note: A [simple example using your exact regex and input works](http://viper-7.com/N4ORfG))

Comment: @nickb I hand-wrote it in.  The only pasted part is the pregmatch.  Including the entire object code would be too much code.  The result of `pregmatch()` is the values which are later brought into the array, which is intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nickb pointed out, your code seems to run just fine. Perhaps when you hand-wrote it in you actually fixed an issue that's in production code. Or the bug you are seeing may be a result of something else that's happening in another part of your code.

[This is what I get](http://viper-7.com/B83tTw) when I run

```
$line = "days: Monday; Thursday; Friday";
preg_match('/^days:\s(.*)$/', $line, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 1)
   var_dump(explode('; ', $matches[1]));
```

> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Monday" [1]=> string(8) "Thursday" [2]=> string(6) "Friday" }

Comment: I see.  Actually, I've found the mistake...  It's unrelated.  Thank you for showing me the way.  If you're curious to know what is happening: a separate private method's pregmatch's regex pattern is pulling data from the `days` line.

Comment: @Wolkpack - So you're saying the mistake you made is unrelated to this question or the sample code you provided?! And the true error is in code that you refused to paste?! **If only somebody said that [half an hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389886/why-is-my-pregmatch-function-returning-the-line-description-which-is-outside#comment16646169_12389886)**!

Answer (score 2):

`$matches[0]` will always contain the entire match (the full string that triggered the match), not just what is captured with parens.  This is standard across most (all?) regular expression libraries.  Your captured expressions start with 1.

Comment: Couldn't I change the regex pattern?  Using a similar method, I've been capturing data on a line that starts like this: `Times (hh:mm): 08:15; 09:00; 12:00`, and `Times (hh:mm): ` isn't included in `[0]`.

Comment: You'll have to provide a complete example (the regex plus the strings you're analyzing) so we can see what would be captured.